# Which one of the different meanings of the word "consensus" to choose

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm struggling with a translation of a technical text describing the process of minimization of a logical function (computer science & tech. stuff) and I don't seem to compe up with any logical explanation for this sentence:

*Rushdi proposed a new procedure of minimization that extends Muroga's procedure by allowing general subsumption and **consensus relations** among the entered products...*

What do you think the phrase "consensus relations" actually means? I have only came up with an assumption that, since consensus can be defined as an opinion that many people agree with, it might relate to some similarities that the entered products might share, e.g. common variables or so.

What do you think about it?
Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: Assuming your text was written by a competent native speaker, I think you need to give more details about the source and context. OED has this definition under ***consensus***: *Genetics. A notional nucleotide or amino acid sequence in which each nucleotide or amino acid is the one most frequently found at that position when a comparison of many sequences of similar structure or function is made. Freq. attrib., esp. in consensus sequence.* Is that relevant? It looks to me like potentially Off Topic domain-specific terminology.

Comment: "Consensus relations" has to be some mangling of a standard phrase in mathematics and related fields, especially since "minimumization" is mentioned. "Entered products" looks like another mangled phrase. "Inner product" maybe?

Comment: I don't think it's so much a mangling as just a metaphorical use of the term _concensus_. And the OP's assumption seems likely: it refers to some quality that many of the products share.